# Blazorise Dropdown does not disappear

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I'm new to Blazorise and I'm using [Blazorise Dropdown](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/dropdown), then I have faced some conflict, when I click the dropdown and then click outside, the dropdown menu does not disappear, any solution?

Thanks

```
<Dropdown @ref="dropdown" Display="Display.InlineBlock">
  <Button Clicked="@ShowMenu" Color="Color.Secondary">Show Menu</Button>
    <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem>Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownDivider />
        <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>


@code {
    Dropdown dropdown;

    Task ShowMenu()
    {
        return dropdown.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `Button` you have to use `DropdownToggle` component:

```
<Dropdown @ref="dropdown" Display="Display.InlineBlock">
    <DropdownToggle Clicked="@ShowMenu" Color="Color.Secondary">Show Menu</DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem>Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownDivider />
        <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>


@code {
    Dropdown dropdown;

    Task ShowMenu()
    {
        return dropdown.Show();
    }
}
```

https://blazorise.com/docs/components/dropdown

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your valuable time and guidance